# Can we customize Liferay tabs to dynamically include image in tab for differentiation?

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay

I want to modify Liferay tabs, as i have three categories of tabs and i want to differentiate them by dynamically adding icon to each of the tab. Is it possible?

Following is my code-snippet.

```
if(Integer.parseInt(group[4].toString())==1){
    tabNames += group[1].toString() + " - (Club),";
}else{
    tabNames += group[1].toString() + ",";
}
```

Inplace of appending "- (xyz)" with Tab-name can I add image?

Comment: Or may be as a over-kill you can modify the `<liferay-ui:tabs>` implementation to have another attribute as `image-src` :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the `<liferay-ui:tabs>` tag, this seems to have no out-of-the-box support for adding images. However, it looks like it will try to find a translation for the value you provide. You *might* be able to cheat when you just provide a translation key for your tab and include the image tag in the actual translation for the key. I have not tested this, but from quickly looking at the sourcecode it looks as if these values are not escaped (as they're fully generated server side).

Of course this will not really work if your groups are fully runtime configurable - because obviously you won't have a proper translation key for everything that might appear in that tab.

If you're asking for any other tab implementation than this one, please rephrase your question, otherwise just add a localization hook to the portlet plugin you're implementing this tab in.